# How to use Authentication and Authorization in Asp.net MVC 4 application?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-4

I am new to MVC and I don't know how to use authentication and authorization attributes in MVC application, I have used these in asp.net webform application as follows;

```
<authentication mode="Forms">
      <forms loginUrl="login.aspx" defaultUrl="home.aspx" protection="All" timeout="2880"/>
    </authentication>
    <authorization>
      <deny users="?"/>
    </authorization>
```

which works fine for me, Now When I use same in MVC application with following changes;

```
<authentication mode="Forms">
        <forms loginUrl="~/Account/Login" defaultUrl="~/Home/Index" timeout="2880" />
    </authentication>
    <authorization>
        <deny users="?"/>
    </authorization>
```

also I have used [Authorize] keyword on ActionResult Login(), which is allowing the users access to the website.
but it shows me error as follows;
The requested page cannot be accessed because the related configuration data for the page is invalid.
Please suggest me what amendments or addition should I do to make it working. Thanks in advance.

Comment: you forgot to add <allow users = "*" /> on authorization part, in web.config

Answer (score 1):

You can go through this [Tutorial](http://chodounsky.net/2012/05/02/basic-authorization-attribute-in-asp-net-mvc/). It might help.